# Passing selectors and action creators as props to a generic component

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

Let’s say I have a custom `Input` component (similar to an HTML `<input/>`) which can be used to represent any value in the Redux store.
The API I’m currently using is that `Input` takes two props `value` and `onChange` and is then used as follows:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const valueA = useSelector(selectValueA);
  const valueB = useSelector(selectValueB);
  const valueC = useSelector(selectValueC);

  const handleChangeA = newValue => dispatch(valueAChanged(newValue));
  const handleChangeB = newValue => dispatch(valueBChanged(newValue));
  const handleChangeC = newValue => dispatch(valueCChanged(newValue));

  return (
    <div>
      <Input value={valueA} onChange={handleChangeA}/>
      <Input value={valueB} onChange={handleChangeB}/>
      <Input value={valueB} onChange={handleChangeC}/>
    </div>
}
```

It works fine but the issue is that whenever `valueA` changes, then the whole `ParentComponent` rerenders instead of just the corresponding `Input`, which causes performance issues and goes against the best practice "have components select only the data they need from the store".

A solution would be to make wrapper components:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <InputA/>
      <InputB/>
      <InputC/>
    </div>
  );
};

const InputA = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const value = useSelector(selectValueA)
  const handleChange = newValue => dispatch(valueAChanged(newValue));
  return <Input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>;
};

const InputB = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const value = useSelector(selectValueB)
  const handleChange = newValue => dispatch(valueBChanged(newValue));
  return <Input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>;
};

const InputC = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const value = useSelector(selectValueC)
  const handleChange = newValue => dispatch(valueCChanged(newValue));
  return <Input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>;
};
…
```

It would fix the problem, but as you can see it is a whole lot of boilerplate that I’d rather avoid.

So I was wondering if I could instead directly pass the selector itself and the action creator as props:

```js
const ParentComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <ConnectedInput selector={selectValueA} actionCreator={valueAChanged}/>
      <ConnectedInput selector={selectValueB} actionCreator={valueBChanged}/>
      <ConnectedInput selector={selectValueC} actionCreator={valueCChanged}/>
    </div>
  );
};

const ConnectedInput = ({selector, actionCreator}) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const value = useSelector(selector);
  const handleChange = newValue => dispatch(actionCreator(newValue));
  return <Input value={value} onChange={handleChange}/>;
};
```

I think it looks very neat and I can’t see anything wrong with it (although I haven’t tried it yet), but it also seems like a pretty unusual pattern, at least I couldn’t find any similar code.

**So is there any problem with it that I’m not seeing? Or is there any other solution to connect generic components to the store?**